# Запуск приложения на сервере приложений

Tags: java, tomcat, запуск, payara

есть код, который нужно запустить на сервере приложений.
Для примера возьмем этот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "/home/folder";
    if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(path))) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код для примера, он просто создает папку.
В перспективе это нужно будет делать по расписанию, но это уже следующий этап задачи.
Вопрос в следующем, в каком формате нужно заархивировать, какие настройки произвести, чтобы этот код при разворачивании
на сервере приложений запустился? Сейчас я попробовал заархивировать этот код в war и jar формате, архив устанавливается на сервер приложений, но не запускается,
что нужно сделать, чтобы запустить это? Пробовал устанавливать на tomcat и payara. Будет полезна любая информация.

Comment: tomcat - контейнер сервлетов, т.е. он предназначен для запуска веб-приложений. в вашем случае никакой tomcat не нужен. запустите с консоли

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за ответ! Может подскажете, есть ли какие-нибудь решения для запуска и управления множеством приложений, если это не веб-приложения?